# Calling Web Api un Umbraco 7

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to call a webapi hosted within the same project as an umbraco website.

I'm using the default webapi routing and calling it in on application start:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

...and set up a controller in an api folder under the controllers folder:

```
        public class ServiceContactFormController : UmbracoApiController
        {
            [HttpGet]
            public HttpResponseMessage Get()
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
            }
        }
```

When I call the webapi using http://localhost:[port]/api/ServiceContactForm I receive a 404.

Are there any additional steps required specifically for Umbraco?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Never mind - for anyone else out there, Umbraco kindly take over the routing and add 'umbraco' to the route, plus you need the action due to the default get, post, etc methods not being recognised...more info here https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/39075-Web-API-routing-not-working.

Working example was:
http://localhost:[port]/umbraco/api/ServiceContactForm/get